# Adding files to PYTHONPATH in OS X

Tags: python, pythonpath

Okay, I am tearing my hair out trying to do this. I've read through dozens of webpages and they've all given me contradictory information, and none of what they've told me to do has worked.

I have a folder full of scripts I downloaded that will only work if they're part of the pythonpath. I want to either move the folder itself into the default path or temporarily (not permanently) add /desktop/search to the path.

What is the default path, and how would I do the latter?

Comment: What version of Python do you use? How did you install it?

Comment: 2.7, it was already installed on my computer (as I believe is normal for OS X).

Comment: Once you've allowed time for through answers, you should accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to the beginning of your python file.

```
import sys    
sys.path.append("/Users/<username>/Desktop/search")
```

Comment: Didn't fix it... am I correct in thinking that if a file is in the path, I will be able to type "python filename.py" into terminal without specifying a location?

Comment: For that you need to change your system PATH as opposed to your PYTHONPATH. Open up terminal and type `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<username>/Desktop/search`Obviously make sure your replace <username> with your username.

Comment: Will that change the path, or just add another path? And will it be permanent or temporary?

Comment: It will change the path by adding another path. It will be temporary. It will only exist in your current shell.

Comment: I typed what you said, then I typed python pacman.py (pacman.py being a script in search) and it still returned no such file or directory. python /desktop/search/pacman.py returns the same errors I was getting before.

Comment: Ohh nevermind. I don't believe that's possible. PATH is used for finding the executable. You should type `python $HOME/Desktop/search/file.py`

Comment: And setting `PYTHONPATH` is almost always a sign that you are doing something to make more work for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical UNIX approach would be to ensure each of the scripts has a proper shebang line, perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

and then installed with the proper permissions (i.e. including `execute` permission) in a directory on your shell search `PATH`, perhaps `/usr/local/bin`.  Then you can invoke a script just with its name:

```
scriptname
```

The pythonic approach would be to install the scripts using Distutils/`easy_install`/`pip` into one of the standard `site-packages` locations for your Python instance and then be able to invoke a script with something like:

```
python2.7 -m scriptname
```

But that may require some work to get everything set up.  The first approach is probably easier.

The bottom-line is that you can't really do exactly what you asked for, that is, be able to type `python scriptname` when the scriptflle can be in an arbitrary directory.